# Display a message dialogue box after registration using struts2?

Tags: struts2

how to display a message dialogue box after registration using struts2?

just as in the case of any registration , after registration to display a message dialogue box with the message "Registration was success full!!!"

can anyone tell me how to do this using struts2?

Comment: Well, I would use the jQuery $.ajax method a open a jQuery $.dialog on the success callback.  If you're not comfortable using jQuery or Javascript directly, you could look at the Struts2 jQuery and Bootstrap plugins.  Using this tag may be your simplest approach:  http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it before personally, but the [Struts2-jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) plugin's [dialog tag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag) looks like a ready-made solution for what you want.

The plugin is popular, very actively maintained, and well-documented.

Comment: +1 for simple solution,but honestly i will not go for this plugin if requirement is just simple as it means adding something for a little use

Comment: That's a good point.  I agree that if this is the only place the plugin would be used, then its not worth the overhead.  But, if the asker intends to implement rich interfaces throughout his application, then this could be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by the dialogue box,it can be a Jquery light box or something or it can be a simple message and can be displayed with [S2 tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/actionmessage.html) like

```
<s:actionmessage />
```

This tag will able you to render message being set in your action class.Alternatively you can create a light-box and display it when the registration is done by sending some variable from the action class and based on that can display the message box.

In order to get more inputs you need to clear following things

1. What kind of message box you want to show.
2. Do you want to show message box on same page (registration)

Comment: in that case do registration using ajax and on successful registration show a message,a simple search with Struts2+Ajax will give you a lot of information and examples